# Shouldnt my Random() write random code? c#

Tags: c#

So im going through a tutorial where you call methods, and withing these methods you want to do use the Random(), in the tutorial he calls his method multiple times and get random results, but when I do it, i get the same result multiple times, all the time. Am I doing something wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MeetAlien();
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");
            MeetAlien();
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");
            MeetAlien();
        
        }

        static void MeetAlien()
        {
            Random numberGen = new Random();
            string name = "X-" + numberGen.Next(10, 9999);
            int age = numberGen.Next(10, 500);

            Console.WriteLine("Hi Im " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Im " + age + " age old");
            Console.WriteLine("And im an alien :)");
        }
```

Comment: Put this line `Random numberGen = new Random();` outside the method as a static member of your class. E.g `static Random numberGen = new Random();`

Comment: Actually, it works Ok for me.

Comment: @Roman You probably tested it against .NET Core (or got lucky).

Comment: @MichaelRandall I tried this and it works 2 out of 3 times. I did a new class and calles it. Why does it only work 2 out of three times you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bad piece of sample code, if it's a faithful reproduction from a tutorial.

The problem is that it's repeatedly constructing `Random` objects without a seed. As the [docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1):

> because the first two Random objects are created in close succession, they are instantiated using identical seed values based on the system clock and, therefore, they produce an identical sequence of random numbers.

(It's talking about a different example, but the explanation is the same)

---

Further down, it's discussed that .NET Framework acts differently to .NET Core, so that indicates that you're running this code on .NET Framework. Maybe the tutorial is meant to be for .NET Core?

Comment: @John - yes, that's discussed further down in the same document linked to. I've updated to say this.

Comment: This is probably right. Our teacher told us to use .Net Framework and not .Core